# On submit the form don't display its POST data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a little experience with Zend Framework, but I like to fiddle with it until it works.
But now I cannot resolve this problem.

I have a form:

```
<?php 
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

protected $notEmpty;

public function init()
{   
    // Create NotEmpty validator
    $notEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();

    // Configure validators for username element
    $notEmpty->setMessage('Gelieve dit veld in te vullen');

    $this->setMethod('post');

    // emailAddress
    $this->addElement('text', 'emailAddress', array(
       'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
       'required' => true,
       'validators'    => array(
            array('validator' => $notEmpty),
            ),
       'label' => 'Emailadres:'
    ));

    // password
    $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
       'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
       'required'      => true,
       'validators'    => array(
           array('validator' => $notEmpty),
           ),
       'label' => 'Wachtwoord:'
    ));

    // submit
    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => 'Inloggen'
    ));
}
}
```

A view:

```
<?= $this->form ?>

<?= $this->postdata ?>
```

And a AccountController:

```
<?php

class AccountController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    echo 'data:'.$this->getRequest()->getPost('emailAddress');
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->postdata = var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());

    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()){
        // THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED
    if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())){
            if ($this->_isValidLogin($form->getValues())){
                // Succes Redirect to the home page
                $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'home');
            }
            else // Not succes Redirect to account page
            {
                $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'account');
            }
        }
```

As you see I put in a comment: // THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED. 
There are more functions in this controller, but those are not relevant for my problem.

Let explain it a bit more.
The very strange behavior is that when I put data in my fields,  $this->view->postdata = var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams() returns no POST data. 
But when I put notting in the login form fields, then I see the POST data. Of course it is empty.
Like this:

```
array
'controller' => string 'account' (length=7)
'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
'module' => string 'default' (length=7)
'emailAddress' => string '' (length=0)
'password' => string '' (length=0)
'submit' => string 'Inloggen' (length=8)
```

Thus, //THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED is actually reached when putting no data in the login form fields :-)

The question is, what are I am doing wrong? Do I deal with the Zend_Controller_Request_Http in the wrong way?

If you need more info, I should give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing down the problem gives new insights!

The problem is in my own code. On some point I redirect to the same page. A redirect means that the $_POST data is also cleared. Those data does - of course - not go with the new page request.

So if someone encounter this problem with Zend Framework, namely you get no POST or GET data on submit of your form, **then you need to check your redirects.**