# Zend Framework - Submit contains no Post Data

Tags: zend-framework, http-post

My issue seems similiar to [On submit the form don't display its POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005340/zend-framework-on-submit-the-form-dont-display-its-post-data) and related questions, but the suggested solutions do not apply to my project, so I am currently not using redirects.

I am attempting to learn Zend Framework.  The current project that I am working on has run into an issue where the the $_POST and $_GET superglobals passed from my form are returning empty.  I have worked to simplify the issue to identify where it is being caused, but I seem to have hit a brick wall.  It seems that no POST data is being sent at all...

My View:

```
<form method="post" action="/character/addsubmit">
    <input type=hidden name='test' id='test' value='test'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
<?php
    class CharacterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
        public function addsubmitAction()
        {
            Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest());

            echo "<br/>\$_POST: <br/>";
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "<br/>\$_GET: <br/>";
            print_r($_GET);
            echo "<br/><br/>";

            if($this->_request->isPost()) {
                echo "\$_POST Found<br/>";
            }
            else {
                echo "\$_POST Not Found <br/>";
            }

            if ($this->_request->isGet()) {
                echo "\$_GET Found<br/>";
            }
            else {
                echo "\$_GET Not Found<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

By Navigating to the form, then submitting (by clicking on the submit button), I receive the following output:

```
object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)#8 (15) {
  ["_paramSources:protected"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(4) "_GET"
    [1] => string(5) "_POST"
  }
  ["_requestUri:protected"] => string(20) "/character/addsubmit"
  ["_baseUrl:protected"] => string(0) ""
  ["_basePath:protected"] => NULL
  ["_pathInfo:protected"] => string(20) "/character/addsubmit"
  ["_params:protected"] => array(3) {
    ["controller"] => string(9) "character"
    ["action"] => string(9) "addsubmit"
    ["module"] => string(7) "default"
  }
  ["_rawBody:protected"] => NULL
  ["_aliases:protected"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["_dispatched:protected"] => bool(true)
  ["_module:protected"] => string(7) "default"
  ["_moduleKey:protected"] => string(6) "module"
  ["_controller:protected"] => string(9) "character"
  ["_controllerKey:protected"] => string(10) "controller"
  ["_action:protected"] => string(9) "addsubmit"
  ["_actionKey:protected"] => string(6) "action"
}

$_POST: 
Array ( ) 
$_GET: 
Array ( ) 

$_POST Not Found 
$_GET Found
```

The one thing that's really throwing me for a loop is that the isGet function is returning true..

Does anyone with more knowledge of Zend have any idea of why I'm having so much trouble submitting forms with this framework?  Is there some configuration that I might have missed or may have set incorrectly that might cause this?

Note: I am using Zend_Form for the actually application, as well as using more of the framework itself, but I have scaled it back in attempting to debug this issue.  If you need any further information about my configuration, I will be able to provide it.

Thanks!

Edit:

My .htaccess file's contents:

[I have removed these lines because it was the wrong file, 
I am still looking for the correct one.]

Comment: Post the contents of your `.htaccess` file (if using Apache)

Comment: Can you provide the Zend_Form class that's producing this form?

Comment: @Phil  I am using GoDaddy Hosting (Yeah, I know, not the best, but it's what I have available.  I will see what I can find for you though.

Comment: @Tim Fountain Would that make a difference?  I was originally using a Zend_Form, but when I realized I was having issues with it, I removed it to simplify debugging.

Comment: Mostly likely cause is a typo in the method="post" part of the form, which isn't present in your example HTML but I thought might be present in the class (e.g. `setMethod('pst')`). Alternatively, is this page online so we can check?

Comment: @Phil I have updated my question with the contents of my .htaccess file.

Comment: @Tim Fountain  I have checked over my code again and have not seen anything out of the ordinary.  It seems strange that the POST variables are not being sent with my example HTML as well.

Comment: @VOIDHand where are your rewrite rules? How does it translate /character/addsubmit to your controller action?

Comment: @Tim Fountain That was the only .htaccess file I was able to find in the files I have access to.  I am currently looking into where else the rewrite rules might be.

Comment: I've done some further testing, and it does look like the rewrite rules are the issue.  I am still looking for further details.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is old, but the following tip may help other readers. I have just experienced this problem, and found the solution here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/127674/mysteriously-empty-post-array

I had just set up a local LAMP development environment, and in populating my database via phpMyAdmin, changed the `post_max_size` directive of `php.ini` to permit the upload of a large SQL dump. Regrettably, I mistyped `1G` as `1GB` in the INI file. PHP interpreted this as a 1 byte limit, which naturally all of my POST submissions exceed, thus they were arriving as empty arrays.

Check your server's error log for something resembling the following:

```
[Sat Oct 01 17:08:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 63 bytes exceeds the limit of 1 bytes in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$this->_request->getParams();
```

Comment: Yes, I have.  Unfortunately, it only returns the section in the "_params::protected" result in the _request list from above, with only the "controller", "action", and "module" fields.  Thanks for the quick response though.